# How to access values from textfield in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, textfield, nested-loops

I have a text_field inside a nested loop.I want to access the value inside all the text fields by using javascript. Here is my html view:

```
<% @empsInProject.each do |empInProject| %>
<%= empInProject.name %>
<% (1..@numberOfMonths).each do |one| %>
<input type="text" id="text1" class="text2">
<% end %>
<% end %>
<button value="check" id="button">Calculate</button>
```

I used the code given below to access the value but it returns the first text field value only.
Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
   var val = $('#text1').val();
    alert(val); 
});
</script>
```

Please help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.text2').each(function(){
     $(this).val();
})
```

User this jQuery function to get each value of the input in your form. This will only work if all your inputs have the class "text2".

Answer (score 0):

HTML `id` should be unique, and `$('#text1')` will only give you first element with id `text1`.

class is for multiple selection.

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var val = $('.text2').map(function() {
     return $(this).val();
   }).join(',');
   alert(val); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

get the text fields by calling `document.getElementsbyClassName("text2")`

it will return a list of input fields then get the values